# Change primary color in materialize css

Tags: sass, npm, gulp, gulp-sass, kong

I am trying to use the kong dashboard (https://github.com/PGBI/kong-dashboard). I would like to change the primary color used in materialize using GULP JS by using another SCSS file. I do not want to change the _variables.scss which is pulled by bower or npm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the ability to add your own primary color. Submitted a pull request and it was accepted. Just set the primary color in app.scss.

Comment: Could you add some details? Maybe an example?

Answer (score 0):

The primary color can be changed in angular's .config using `$mdThemingProvider` here is an example

```
$mdThemingProvider.theme("default")
        .primaryPalette('grey', {
            'default': '600', // by default use shade 400 from the pink palette for primary intentions
            'hue-1': '100', // use shade 100 for the <code>md-hue-1</code> class
            'hue-2': '600', // use shade 600 for the <code>md-hue-2</code> class
            'hue-3': 'A100' // use shade A100 for the <code>md-hue-3</code> class
        })
```

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme

All the colors for your app can be set there

Comment: Hi, i was able to make a change using materialize itself. I submitted a Pull Request and it got accepted :) thanks though